# UITableView inside a UITableViewCell getting hide when scrolls the outer tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an app where the user can add events to a particular contact in contact list. So, if the user scrolls the contact list, each contact will show the list of events in it. My problem is when I scroll down the outer table view, the events are showing up fine, but when scrolling up it hides some of the events(i.e., `UITableViewCells`). And again if I start scrolls down its working fine and again scrolls up the events are hiding. For eg., If a contact has three events in it, it shows only first two and last one is hiding. Checked will the datasource methods, all are fine(i.e., the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` getting called 4 times).

My `CellForRowAtIndexPath` of inner tableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventViewCell";

EventsCellAtViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    // load a new cell from the nib file
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventsCellAtViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = self.eventsAtCell;

    self.eventsAtCell = nil;
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

cell.event = [_eventsFeed eventAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
```

}

Please help me out in this issue. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Why do you use UITableView inside UITableViewCell - that sounds wired at least :) Why not keep data in 1 UITableView with different cells ?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a vertical scroll view inside another vertical scroll view is often a cause of problems. The user often gets too confused about which view should have scrolled when they dragged up or down.

In this case it sounds like the data inside the cell is taller than the cell itself, causing it to need to scroll to display it all.

Instead of trying to scroll the data inside a cell, you should make the cell tall enough to display all its data.  The heightForRowAtIndexpath method will give you the chance to change each cell's height.

It also looks like this is based on older Apple sample code.  The UINib method of instantiating cells is preferable to using "loadNibNamed" to reset the IBOutlet with a new cell.  Using storyboards is more modern than both of these methods.